# What's wrong with this nested loop?

Tags: python, loops

I am writing a program that should have the output that looks like this.

```
111111111
222222222
333333333
444444444
555555555
666666666
777777777
888888888
999999999
```

I have written this code :

```
for i in range(10):
  for j in range(10):
    print (str(i) * i)
print()
```

but this doesn't seem right!

Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you sure you need two loops here?

Answer (score 3):

You just need one for loop since you have a fix repetition for each number, i.e., 9. Also, you need to replace `range(10)` by `range(1,10)` because `range(10)` would by default start from 0 but you don't need `000000000`

```
for i in range(1,10):
    print (str(i) * 9)
```

**Output**

```
111111111
222222222
333333333
444444444
555555555
666666666
777777777
888888888
999999999
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that this is a linear sequence, you can thus use `range`.

```
print(*range(111111111, 1000000000, 111111111), sep='\n')
```

### Output

```
111111111
222222222
333333333
444444444
555555555
666666666
777777777
888888888
999999999
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[print(str(i)*len(range(1,10))) for i in range(1,10)]
```

> ```
> 111111111
> 222222222
> 333333333
> 444444444
> 555555555
> 666666666
> 777777777
> 888888888
> 999999999
> ```

Expanded:

```
for i in range(1,10):
    print(str(i) * len(range(1,10)))
```